# Expected a value of type BuildContext , but got one of type 'JSobject'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create star effect like falling random stars but got this error:

> Expected a value of  type BuildContext, but got one of type 'JSobject'

When code runs, it will create an effect of random stars based on particle system. Maybe I need to cast the context variable to a `BuildContext` or something like this.

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(const FallingStarsParticleSystem());
}


class FallingStarsParticleSystem extends StatefulWidget {
  const FallingStarsParticleSystem({super.key});

  @override
  _FallingStarsParticleSystemState createState() =>
      _FallingStarsParticleSystemState();
}

class _FallingStarsParticleSystemState extends State<FallingStarsParticleSystem>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late List<Particle> _particles;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _controller.repeat();

    _particles = List.generate(
      100,
      (index) => Particle(
        x: Random().nextDouble() * MediaQuery.of(context as BuildContext).size.width,
        y: 0.0,
        vx: Random().nextDouble() * 10.0,
        vy: -Random().nextDouble() * 100.0,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            _controller.value += details.delta.dx / 100.0;
          },
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ParticlePainter(
              particles: _particles,
              time: _controller.value,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Particle {
  double x;
  double y;
  double vx;
  double vy;

  Particle({
    required this.x,
    required this.y,
    required this.vx,
    required this.vy,
  });

  void update(double time) {
    x += vx * time;
    y += vy * time;
    vy += 9.8 * time;

    if (y > MediaQuery.of(context as BuildContext).size.height) {
      x = Random().nextDouble() * MediaQuery.of(context as BuildContext).size.width;
      y = 0.0;
      vx = Random().nextDouble() * 10.0;
      vy = -Random().nextDouble() * 100.0;
    }
  }
}

class ParticlePainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<Particle> particles;
  double time;

  ParticlePainter({
    required this.particles,
    required this.time,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (Particle particle in particles) {
      paintParticle(canvas, particle, time);
    }
  }

  void paintParticle(Canvas canvas, Particle particle, double time) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    double x = particle.x;
    double y = particle.y;
    double radius = 3.0;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, y), radius, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import `import 'dart:js';`
also your `update` method inside `Particle` class uses a `BuildContext` but it's not passed to it from anywhere, you need to pass it via the constructor